# What year connects all these 10 hints?

Tags: word

**Hint #1**

> An Earthquake + 200

**Hint #2**

> Birth of Mr. Green

**Hint #3**

> I'm MC Roman ML25

**Hint #4**

> Water in the US

**Hint #5**

> Birth of Miss Pretty

**Hint #6**

> Birth of "Leonard"!

**Hint #7**

> Can you bend it like Hint 7?

**Hint #8**

> The very first Viking

**Hint #9**

> Do you recall the Iron Maiden Torture device?

**Hint #10**

> Well, back then the UK wanted to be in EU

Comment: Is the earthquake +220 and not +200?

Comment: Precisely + 220 years

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> 1975

2. Birth of Mr. Green

> CeeLo Green was born in 1975.

3. I'm MC Roman ML25

> MCML is 1950 in Roman numerals, add 25 to get 1975.

4. Water in the US

> The Watergate scandal happened in 1975.

5. Birth of Miss Pretty

> Angelina Jolie ("pretty" in French) was born in 1975. (from @dmg)

6. Birth of "Leonard"!

> Johnny Galecki, who plays "Leonard" in *The Big Bang Theory*, was born in 1975. (from @IanMcDonald)

7. Can you bend it like Hint 7?

> "Can you bend it like Beckham?" referring to David Beckham, who was born in 1975. (from @IanMcDonald)

8. The very first Viking

> The Viking 1 probe was launched in 1975.

9. Do you recall the Iron Maiden Torture device?

> The band Iron Maiden was founded in 1975.

10. Well, back then the UK wanted to be in EU

> In 1975, the United Kingdom voted to stay in the European Economic Community.

Comment: Johnny Galecki and David Beckham.

Comment: #1 is the "Great East Siberian” earthquake of February 1, 1725

Comment: Also #5 seems to be something about a horse

Comment: @dmg #1 Is not about an Earthquake in 1725.  #5 is about a person who is not french, but think in the french language

Comment: @Oak I see what you did there with #5. Miss Pretty -> Mlle Jolie -> Angelina Jolie, born 1975.

Comment: Still Missing one though

Comment: #1 Refered to the 1775 (1775 + 200 = 1975) Lisbon, where an Earthquake caused severe damages, and also provoked a Major Fire and a Tsunami.

Comment: @Oak That earthquake was in 1755, not 1775.

Comment: As I said, (1775 + 200 = 1975)

Comment: @Oak 1755 and 1775 are different. The earthquake was in 1755. 1755+200=1955.